# Joins (Oracle SQL) and Total Sum trouble

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sum

thanks in advance for your help. I have a number of tables, find them here: [Click for image of ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pz7Y.png)

Business Sponsors can be either businesses, or alumni. These business sponsors can make donations. These donations can be monetary, travel grants etc. however their value is stored in the following format: $x,xxx under "value" in 'Donation'.

I have to list all the business sponsors (BusinessID AND AlumniID) who have donated a **total amount greater than $25,000 value**. The results must be sorted in descending order of the total donated amount.

I've screenshotted results for DESC queries to Alumnus, Donation and BusinessSponser if that helps: [DESC QUERIES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX18A.png)

I'm really unsure how to proceed forward, any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance again.

Comment: Do the AlumniID and BusinessID fields have the same data types / structure?

Comment: Isnt clear the relationship between Alumnus and BusinessSponser.

Comment: BusinessSponser uses Alumnus 'AlumniID' as the foreign key. The AlumniID and BusinessID field DO have the same data type (int).

Comment: Having the AlumniID field in BusinessSponsor connects it directly to table Alumnus, which is not represented on your diagram.

Comment: Also, do you want names as well as ID's to be listed?

Comment: Hi Toonice. Yes, I need the names as well as ID's to be listed. The table 'Alumnus' was represented on the middle left. Rather than the ERD, I have included some screenshots of responses from DESC queries.

Comment: I have edited my answer further.  Please feel free to review and comment upon the revisions.

Comment: Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) We need sample data and desire output to find an answer faster, otherwise we will be wasting time guessing what you need. You also could create your schema with data using **http://www.sqlfiddle.com**

Comment: Fix your bad questions, don't vandalise them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.AlumnID, SUM(D.Value)
FROM BusinessSponser B
JOIN Alumnus A
  ON B.AlumnID = A.AlumnID
JOIN Donation D
  ON D.BusinessID = B.BusinessID
GROUP BY A.AlumnID

UNION 

SELECT A.AlumnID, SUM(D.Value)
FROM Alumnus A
JOIN Donation D
  ON D.AlumnID = B.AlumnID 
GROUP BY A.AlumnID
```

Comment: This code did not work. I appreciate your contribution however.

Comment: didnt work because an error or because dont return the result you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
SELECT A.AlumniID,
       B.FirstName,
       B.LastName,
       A.BusinessID,
       C.BusinessName
       A.TotalDonation
FROM ( SELECT AlumniID,
              BusinessID,
              SUM( Value ) AS TotalDonation
       FROM Donation
       WHERE AlumniID IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY AlumniID
       UNION SELECT AlumniID,
                    BusinessID,
                    SUM( Value ) AS TotalDonation
             FROM Donation
             WHERE BusinessID IS NOT NULL
             GROUP BY BusinessID ) A
     LEFT JOIN Alumnus B
            ON A.AlumniID = B.AlumniID
     LEFT JOIN BusinessSponsor C
            ON A.BusinessID = C.BusinessID;
```

I started with the query -

```
SELECT AlumniID,
       BusinessID,
       SUM( Value ) AS TotalDonation
FROM Donation
WHERE AlumniID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY AlumniID
```

This gives us the `AlumniID` and `TotalDonation` for all of the Alumni.  `BusinessID` was reproduced here so I could merge the above query with the below query to form one query...

From here I performed a `LEFT JOIN` with the Alumnus table and another `LEFT JOIN` with the BusinessSponsor table to get the resulting list.

I recommend you perform further research on -

- The various types of JOINS and their characteristics
- NULL values and how to detect and handle them
- SUM and GROUP BY

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post below.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, this code didn't work unfortunately. I have attached responses from DESC queries sent to the tables, you'll find the image in the original question above ^^^ 

Again, I appreciate you helping me out. Kudos to you, good sir, you're probably a gentleman and a scholar.